# When is the Hamiltonian constant?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, hamilton-equations

In the context of optimal control, when is the Hamiltonian constant?

I know that, generally, when $H$ is not *explicitly* a function of time, it is going to be a constant, but I just did a problem where the Hamiltonian switched from a constant value to another constant value at some later time, like a piecewise function. So, can anyone clarify when the Hamiltonian is truly a constant, and when it is a piecewise function?

Comment: Could you give details of the problem you mentioned? Perhaps $H$ does depend on time there, but in a way not obvious from its analytic expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to be more precise when talking about something being constant. A constant is a number or vector.

In optimal control theory, the Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}$ can additionally be a function of $x(t)$, $u(t)$ and $\lambda(t)$. Hence, it is not constant. If you are only considering invariance with time then

$$\dfrac{d\mathcal{H}}{dt}=\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial \lambda}\dfrac{\partial \lambda}{\partial t}$$.

Comment: I'd like to add that this answer does a slight disservice by not initially being explicit that the Hamiltonian may be a function of time, and including the partial of the Hamiltonian with respect to time, and saying that term goes to zero under the assumptions of time invariance. Also, we should probably be precise with the total derivative definition.

Answer (score 1):

Constant Hamiltonian in Optimal Control Theory are related to the Beltrami Identity appearing in Calculus of Variations.

In Calculus of Variations, if the Lagrangian $ \mathcal{L} $ don't explicetly depend on time such that $ J = \int \mathcal{L}(x,\dot{x}) dt $ then the Beltrami Identity $ \mathcal{L} - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}_{\alpha}} \dot{x}_{\alpha} = C $ holds where $ C $ is a constant.

In Optimal Control Theory the Lagrangian are given by $ \mathcal{L} = L(t, \mathbf{x},\mathbf{u}) + \dot{\phi}(t,\mathbf{x} ) + \boldsymbol{\lambda} \left( \mathbf{f}(t,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u}) - \mathbf{\dot{x}} \right)  $ where $ L $ are Running Cost, $ \phi $ are terminal cost an $ f $ are system dynamics. If all those three quantities don't explicetly depend on time then neither the Lagrangian $ \mathcal{L} $ does and the Costate Equation can be re-written using the Beltrami Identity, and it will collapses into $ H=C $

$ \mathcal{L} - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}_{\alpha}} \dot{x}_{\alpha} = C $

$ \left\{ H + \frac{d \phi}{dt} -
\lambda_{\theta}\dot{x}_{\theta} \right\} -
\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot{x}_{\alpha}}
\left\{
H + \frac{d \phi}{dt} - \lambda_{\theta}\dot{x}_{\theta}
\right\}
\dot{x}_{\alpha} = C $

$ H +
\frac{\partial \phi}{d x_{\beta}} \dot{x}_{\beta} -
\lambda_{\theta}\dot{x}_{\theta} -
\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot{x}_{\alpha}}
\left\{
\frac{\partial \phi}{d x_{\beta}} \dot{x}_{\beta} -
\lambda_{\theta}\dot{x}_{\theta}
\right\}
\dot{x}_{\alpha} = C $

$ H +
\frac{\partial \phi}{d x_{\beta}} \dot{x}_{\beta} -
\lambda_{\theta}\dot{x}_{\theta} -
\frac{\partial \phi}{d x_{\alpha}} \dot{x}_{\alpha} +
\lambda_{\alpha}
\dot{x}_{\alpha} = C $

$ H = C $

$  $